# Xamarin.iOS UITableView programmatically hide separator lines

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am creating a tableView in my `ViewDidLoad` and setting up a custom `Source` and `Cell`. That all works great. However the `UITableView` is displaying separator lines behind my custom view. I can comment out my code for the custom appearance so that the all that loads on screen is an empty `UITableView` and it still displays the separator lines even though I have set the `separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None`

```
var table = new UITableView(View.Bounds);
table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
table.SeparatorColor = UIColor.Clear;
table.TableFooterView = new UIView(CGRect.Empty);
Add(table);
```

I have also tried setting there color to clear and a blank footer to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

I know time to time Xamarin ios could be strange, but finally I was able to make it work.
You have to run this code in the ViewDidLayoutSubviews and it works

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

        table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need the following within your override the UITableViewController's  `ViewDidLoad` method (I take it you have subclassed a ViewController for this purpose):

```
table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
```

That should do the trick.

Regards,

John

Comment: As shown in my example above, I am already running that line of code and does not work for some reason. Thank you, Kyle

Comment: I didn't want to do it this way in this scenario, but for now what I have done to get around it is having a table already setup on my storyboard with the separator style set to none in the properties and then appliing all my templates etc programmatically. Just seems wierd to me that setting the separator style to none in the story board properties works but doing it in code via "table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;" does not work.